# Phantom JS for Node, use print stylesheet?

Tags: node.js, stylesheet, phantomjs

I'm using Node JS to generate PDFs.

Is there a way to get Phantom JS to screenshot pages using the print stylesheet instead of the screen one?

At the moment I have the print stylesheet all set up and good to go, but Phantom JS is being recognised as a screen device instead of print.

Here's a snipped of code so you can see what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance!

```
    var date = Date.now();
    var images = [];

    capture(results.length, 0);

    function capture(pagesLength, pageId) {
        if (pagesLength <= 0) {
            stopCapture();
        }
        else {
            snapshot(pagesLength, pageId);
        }
    }

    function snapshot(pagesLength, pageId) {
        phantom.create(function (ph) {
            ph.createPage(function (page) {
                page.open("http://127.0.0.1:3000/#/pages/" + results[pageId]["_id"], function (status) {
                    var fileName = results[pageId]["_id"] + ".jpeg";
                    images.push(fileName);
                    page.render("public/temp/" + date + "/" + fileName, {format: 'jpeg', quality: '100'}, function () {
                        pagesLength--;
                        pageId++;
                        ph.exit();
                        if (pagesLength <= 0) {
                            mergeImages();
                        } else {
                            snapshot(pagesLength, pageId);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change it, because it is hard coded in QtWebkit. There are two approaches that you can try.

---

**First:**

If your print stylesheet is separate from the screen styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="printstyle.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

then you can remove the screen style and change the media type of the print stylesheet inside `evaluate`:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("link:not([media='print']), style"), function(el){
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
});
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("link[media='print']"), function(el){
    el.media = "screen";
});
```

*(^ untested)*

This should yield:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="printstyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

and you will probably have to wait a little until phantom applies the styles.

---

**Second:**

Compile your own phantomjs version with the changed media type.

You can currently find it under [line 125 of `src / qt / src / 3rdparty / webkit / Source / WebCore / page / FrameView.cpp`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebCore/page/FrameView.cpp#L125):

```
FrameView::FrameView(Frame* frame)
...
    , m_mediaType("screen")
...
```

*(^ also untested)*

Change `screen` to `print`, compile it and have fun.

Comment: this works but it's not enough as you have to take into account `@media screen and ...` as well. see also this comment on phantomjs issue tracker: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10374#issuecomment-267044771